# Instruct Maven to use Ivy's generated classpath

Tags: maven, ivy, pom.xml

We are adding new code to an existing project that uses a custom build system developed with **Ant** and **Ivy** for dependency management.

Our new team is used to **Maven** and its features like testing execution, cobertura reports, etc.

Our question is: is it viable to add a pom.xml matching the current project structure, but instruct Maven to load its classpath from the "lib" dir already filled by Ivy?
In other words: we want to use Maven without its dependency management.

One *really dirty* approach would be to generate one big jar from the libdir and config the pom.xml to include just that... but we believe there should be cleaner approach.

Any idea or recommendation?

Note: we are not interested in generating a pom.xml with dependencies from the Ivy config, we just want Maven to rely on Ivy's generated classpath. No need to discriminate between test/runtime/compile classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is our final setup to solve this:

- For each Ivy legacy project, use **ivy:makepom** and manual inspection to figure out the dependencies that we need to send to the new projects (Maven-based). This is a one-time process for each project.
- Modify the legacy build system in a way that, every time a project is built, the identified dependencies are also exported to a mvn repo. Because de build machine holds the internal repo, we just use **mvn install**.
- In the new maven projects, declare each dependency in the pom.xml and make sure the build system runs maven builds after the legacy builds.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the `system` scope to define your dependencies in maven.  This allows maven to use the jars downloaded by ivy for its dependencies.

e.g.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
      <version>a.b.c</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/artifact-a.b.c.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks... but that still forces us to generate one big jar (not very nice...), or state all the dependencies one by one (which is a lot of duplication effort that we don't really need). Do you know if we can point it to a libs dir instead one .jar?

Comment: @Sebastian.  Well, if you used maven alone, you would declare each dependency:)

Comment: Yes :).. but our project augments and existing project that uses Ivy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [makepom task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/makepom.html) will be helpful, it creates a pom from the ivy file.

Example from that page:

```
<ivy:makepom ivyfile="${basedir}/path/to/ivy.xml" pomfile="${basedir}/path/to/module.pom" conf="default,runtime">
   <mapping conf="default" scope="compile"/>
   <mapping conf="runtime" scope="runtime"/>
   <dependency group="com.acme" artifact="acme-logging" version="1.0" optional="true"/>
</ivy:makepom>
```

Comment: We looked into this. The only issue is that we would need to script something to merge the generated POM with the one already in place every time the Ivy config changes. In this scenario, we are inclined to a simpler option: just put a task that creates a big .jar and reference it from Maven as explained by Raghuram. I'll keep the question open in case someone comes up with a better idea :)

Comment: Maybe the best solution would be to use makepom once and stop using ivy after that. I feel that any of the other approaches will result in some serious headache later :). Mixing two dependency managers seems risky.

Comment: Ivy will still be used in the other project. Indeed, something could change on the Ivy side, and not correctly flow to the Maven side later. But I don't see this as a risk, but as a complexity we need to properly address with some process (manual/automatic).